# Orchard CMS Navigation alternate per zone

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

This seems like it would be pretty simple but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.  I'm simply trying to add a CSS class to the <ul> tag of my main navigation.  I understand I can override the Menu.cshtml view in my theme however this would override every menu.  I want to target my main menu specifically (really the menu widget in the Navigation zone).  I attempted to use the Vandelay Classy module however this adds the class name to the most outer element (which in the menu's case is an  tag).

Specifically, I am using the Twitter bootstrap and need to add the classes "nav nav-justified" to the <ul> object to conform.  Again, this should only effect 1 menu (namely the menu in the navigation zone).  I only plan to have 1 menu in the navigation zone, however if there's an alternative to targeting every menu in that zone (in the off chance I do have multiple menus in that zone) I'm all ears.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First solution: applying a class to the outermost element is in principle all you need, as you can then use nested selectors.

Second solution: you can enable the widget alternates feature, which will give you new alternates based on zone names.

Comment: I'm aware of the first solution however I was hoping to avoid re-inventing the wheel as I want to utilize the CSS that comes with Bootstrap (which requires the class names to be placed on certain elements).

For the second solution, I have the widget alternates feature enabled and shape tracing however I can't seem to find a suggested alternate that would work for the zone name.  If the zone is "Navigation", what would the alternate view name look like?

Comment: For what shape did you look for alternates?

Comment: Ended up using a widget alternate.  Not the cleanest but I was able to accomplish what I wanted.